# pdal: why does filters.hag and filters.ferry with HeightAboveGround=Z reset original points to Z=0?

Tags: point-cloud, pdal

pdal: why does filters.hag and filters.ferry with HeightAboveGround=Z reset original points to Z=0?

I'm essentially trying out the example-3, given here:

https://pdal.io/stages/filters.hag.html#example-3

```
{
  "pipeline":[
  ...
  take input and perhaps do some other stuff
  ...
    {
      "type":"filters.smrf",
      "ignore":"Classification[7:7]", // ignore "noise points" from input
      "slope":0.05,
      "window":45,
      "threshold":0.8,
      "scalar":1.25
    },
    {
        "type":"filters.hag"
    },
    {
        "type":"filters.ferry",
        "dimensions":"HeightAboveGround=Z"
    },
  ...
  do output
  ...
  ]
}
```

Results, when plotted:

[image]

The code above recreates the problem in the sense that if I remove the filters.hag and filters.ferry, the red cloud would be the same as the blue one.

Is there something I could do, to add the offsets back to the output?